# R - Hide/Unhide selectInput when cursor position in specific rmarkdown or html tabsets R shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I have a question about to hide/unhide selected input box if I click to other tabsets.

In R shiny dashboard, tabsets setup by Rmarkdown html tabset `{.tabset}` instead of using `shiny::tabsetPanel`

````
---
title: "Demo"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# {.tabset}

```{r}
shiny::selectizeInput("sel_ip", "Select input", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
```
## Tabset 1

```{r mtcars}
DT::datatable(mtcars)
```

## Tabset 2

```{r mtcars1}
DT::datatable(mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 21,])
```

## Tabset 3

```{r cars}
DT::datatable(cars)
```
````

[image]

Output will

- Appear select box when I click Tabset 1 or Tabset 2
- Disappear select box when I click to Tabset 3

I think I add javascript options to control hide/unhide, but in inspector, I can not find difference in `div(id = ...)`, I can see difference in  `<li class = ...>`, example: I in Tabset 1 - `<li class = "active">`, another tabsets `<li class = "">` or not disappear `class`, or different by `href="#section-tabset-1"`... (see more in picture below). I don't know how to do it yet.

[image]

Can you have any solutions with these code lines?
Thank you so much.